Do positive functionals on a self-dual cone extend to the whole space?
Let $\mathcal H$ be a Hilbert space with self-dual cone $\mathcal H^+ = \{\,\xi\in\mathcal H \mid \langle\xi|\mathcal H^+\rangle \ge 0\,\}$.  Suppose we have a function $f\colon \mathcal H^+ \to [0,+\infty)$ which is

homogeneous, $f(\lambda\xi) = \lambda(f\xi)$ if $\xi\in\mathcal H^+$ and $\lambda\ge0$,
additive, $f(\xi+\eta) = f(\xi) + f(\eta)$ if $\xi$, $\eta\in\mathcal H^+$,
continuous.

Does $f$ extend to a bounded linear functional $\mathcal H \to \mathbb C$?
Any $\xi \in \mathcal H$ has a unique Jordan decomposition $\xi = \sum_{k=0}^3 i^k\xi_k$ as a polarized sum of orthogonal vectors $\xi_k \in \mathcal H^+$.  Any extension must satisfy $f(\xi) = \sum i^kf(\xi_k)$.  So the question is whether this defines a linear functional on all of $\mathcal H$.
The ordered space $\mathcal H$ is a vector lattice if and only if it is of the form $L^2(Z,\nu)$ for a locally compact space $Z$ and a positive Radon measure $\nu$, and $\mathcal H^+ = L^2(Z,\nu)^+$.  (Iochum, Cones autopolaires et algèbres de Jordan, Proposition I.3.6.; also this question.)  So in this case the answer is obviously yes.  In general this has a flavor somewhat like Gleason's theorem.

This is a lot simpler than Gleason’s Theorem. It’s really just algebraic manipulation. First, we define $f’(\xi - \eta) = f(\xi) - f(\eta)$ for all $\xi, \eta \in H^+$. (Note that I’m not assuming $\xi - \eta$ is a Jordan decomposition.) To show this is well-defined, assume $\xi - \eta = \xi’ - \eta’$ for $\xi, \eta, \xi’, \eta’ \in H^+$. Then $\xi + \eta’ = \xi’ + \eta$. So by additivity of $f$, we have $f(\xi) + f(\eta’) = f(\xi’) + f(\eta)$ and thus $f(\xi) - f(\eta) = f(\xi’) - f(\eta’)$. Hence, $f’$ is well-defined on the real linear span of $H^+$. It is not hard to check that $f’$ extends $f$ and that it is additive and positive homogeneous. To show it is real linear, just note that,
$$f’(-(\xi - \eta)) = f’(\eta - \xi) = f(\eta) - f(\xi) = -(f(\xi) - f(\eta)) = -f’(\xi - \eta)$$
for any $\xi, \eta \in H^+$.
Now, we note that the real and imaginary part can be separated, in the following sense: if $h = ik$ for $h, k$ in the real linear span of $H^+$, then $h = k = 0$. Indeed, this just follows from taking inner products with $\xi \in H^+$. The LHS of $h = ik$ always yields a real number, while the RHS always yields a purely imaginary one, so $\langle \xi|h \rangle = 0$ for all $\xi \in H^+$. Since $H^+$ spans the entire space, we have $h = 0$. From this, we define,
$$f’’(h + ik) = f’(h) + if’(k)$$
whenever $h, k$ are in the real linear span of $H^+$. By the above separation result and the fact that $f’$ is real linear, it is not hard to check $f’’$ is a complex linear extension of $f$ to the complex linear span of $H^+$, which is just $H$.
To check $f’’$ is bounded, we note that $f$ is bounded, by positive homogeneity and using the usual proof that continuous linear maps are bounded. Then the result follows by Jordan decomposition and Pythagorean theorem.
